# Canvas Fill Page Width and Height

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

http://jsbin.com/oMUtePo/1/edit

I've been having a pain trying to get canvas to fill the whole page.

I tried using...

```
canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
```

It filled the width, but not the height, and the drawing board was drawing 1px lines, which is not what I want.

When using 100% for width and height in CSS the width is scaled, and the height is cut, when drawing it looks as if a raster image was scaled significantly larger in ms paint and there's a large offset on onmousedown drawing which is obviously not what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Full Code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>HTML5 Canvas Drawing Board</title>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#myCanvas {
    cursor: crosshair;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var curColor = $('#selectColor option:selected').val();
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,500);

    if(myCanvas){
        var isDown = false;
        var canvasX, canvasY;
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;

        $(myCanvas)
        .mousedown(function(e){
            isDown = true;
            ctx.beginPath();
            canvasX = e.pageX - myCanvas.offsetLeft;
            canvasY = e.pageY - myCanvas.offsetTop;
            ctx.moveTo(canvasX, canvasY);
        })
        .mousemove(function(e){
            if(isDown !== false) {
                canvasX = e.pageX - myCanvas.offsetLeft;
                canvasY = e.pageY - myCanvas.offsetTop;
                ctx.lineTo(canvasX, canvasY);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function(e){
            isDown = false;
            ctx.closePath();
        });
    }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas">
        Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 canvas technology.
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the absolute size in pixels on the canvas element and not with CSS as you do in the demo, so first remove the following lines from the CSS rule:

```
#myCanvas {
    cursor: crosshair;
    position: absolute;
    /*width: 100%; Remove these */
    /*height: 100%;*/
}
```

Then add this to your code - you need to use `clientWidth/Height` of the `window` object.

```
myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
```

**[Your modified JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/oMUtePo/2/)**.